# Android Firebase OTP verification is not sending sms

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, one-time-password

I am trying to use firebase authentication with Otp in my android app and this code is not working.
It is not sending the SMS and also the toast section i mentioned after comment is not executing. 
  package com.example.esport;

```
public class otpverification extends AppCompatActivity {
  private Button verify;
  private EditText code;
  private String number,verification_code;
  private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
  private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mcallBack;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_otpverification);
        verify =findViewById(R.id.otpverifiaction_verify);
        code=findViewById(R.id.otpverification_otp);
        number=getIntent().getStringExtra("ph_number");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),number,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

//This toast is also not executing on the app
            sendsms(number);

```
        mcallBack = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onCodeSent(String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
                super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
                verification_code=s;
            }


        };
    }

    private void sendsms(String number) {
        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                number,600, TimeUnit.SECONDS, TaskExecutors.MAIN_THREAD,mcallBack
        );
    }

    public void verify(View view){
        String input_code=code.getText().toString();
        if(verification_code.equals(""))
        {
            verifyPhoneNumber(verification_code,input_code);
        }

    }

    private void verifyPhoneNumber(String verification_code, String input_code) {
        PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verification_code,input_code);
        signInWithPhone(credential);
    }

    public void signInWithPhone(PhoneAuthCredential credential){
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful())
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sucessful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you're using country code for sending SMS, like add +91 for India to the number.

Comment: Already added the country code

Comment: okay, call sendSms(number) after `mCallback = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {} `

Answer (score 0):

Please Send me error 
Check or fill SHA1 key from studio to firebase

Phone number Activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    numberBt.setOnClickListener {

        var mnumber : String = numberEt.text.toString()

        var intent = Intent(this,OtpScreen::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("number",mnumber)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}}
```

Otp Activity

```
open class OtpScreen : AppCompatActivity(), OnCompleteListener<AuthResult> {

val REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 1

private var mVerificationId: String? = null

private var mAuth: FirebaseAuth? = null

lateinit var mobile: String

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_otp_screen)

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

    mobile = intent.getStringExtra("number")

    sendVerificationCode(mobile)

    if (checkAndRequestPermissions()) {
        // carry on the normal flow, as the case of  permissions  granted.
    }

    signInBt.setOnClickListener {
        var code: String = otpEt.text.toString()

        verifyVerificationCode(code)

    }

}

private fun sendVerificationCode(mobile: String) {

    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
        "+91$mobile",
        60, TimeUnit.SECONDS, TaskExecutors.MAIN_THREAD, mCallbacks
    )
}

var mCallbacks = object : PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
    override fun onVerificationCompleted(phoneAuthCredential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
        var code = phoneAuthCredential.smsCode

        otpEt.setText(code)

        if (code != null) {
            verifyVerificationCode(code)
        }
    }

    override fun onVerificationFailed(p0: FirebaseException) {
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext,p0.message.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    override fun onCodeSent(p0: String, p1: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken) {
        super.onCodeSent(p0, p1)

        mVerificationId = p0

    }
}

private fun verifyVerificationCode(code: String) { //creating the credential
    val credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(mVerificationId!!, code)
    //signing the user
    signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential)
}

private fun signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
    mAuth!!.signInWithCredential(credential)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, OnCompleteListener { task ->

            if (task.isSuccessful){
                var intent = Intent(this,ProfileActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }

            else{
                Toast.makeText(this,task.exception.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

        })
}

override fun onComplete(p0: Task<AuthResult>) {
}


private val receiver: BroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent) {
        if (intent.action.equals("otp", ignoreCase = true)) {
            val message = intent.getStringExtra("message")
            otpEt.setText(message)
        }
    }
}

 open fun checkAndRequestPermissions(): Boolean {
    val permissionSendMessage = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
        this,
        Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS
    )
    val receiveSMS =
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS)
    val readSMS = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS)
    val listPermissionsNeeded: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
    if (receiveSMS != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_MMS)
    }
    if (readSMS != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_SMS)
    }
    if (permissionSendMessage != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
    }
    if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this,
            listPermissionsNeeded.toTypedArray(),
            REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS
        )
        return false
    }
    return true
}

override fun onResume() {
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(receiver, IntentFilter("otp"))
    super.onResume()
}

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(receiver)
}}
```

Auto fill otp Class

```
class MySMSBroadCastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
override fun onReceive(
    context: Context,
    intent: Intent
) { // Get Bundle object contained in the SMS intent passed in
    val bundle = intent.extras
    var smsm: Array<SmsMessage?>? = null
    var sms_str = ""
    if (bundle != null) { // Get the SMS message
        val pdus = bundle["pdus"] as Array<Any>?
        smsm = arrayOfNulls(pdus!!.size)
        for (i in smsm.indices) {
            smsm[i] =
                SmsMessage.createFromPdu(pdus[i] as ByteArray)
            sms_str += smsm[i]?.getMessageBody().toString()
            val Sender = smsm[i]?.getOriginatingAddress()
            //Check here sender is yours
            val smsIntent = Intent("otp")
            smsIntent.putExtra("message", sms_str)
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(smsIntent)
        }
    }
}}
```